# SQLite: How to create columns and indices with a single SQL command

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm getting an error when running the following, and I think its the `CREATE INDEX` part because the query worked on previous update before uninstalling the app and reinstalling it.

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME    = "db_name.db";
   private static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGES = "create table messages"
           + "("
           + "_id" + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
           + "message_id" + " text not null, "
           + "sender" + " text not null, "
           + "recipient" + " text DEFAULT NA, "
           + "message" + " text not null, "
           + "shared" + " text not null, "
           + "sent" + " Boolean DEFAULT false, "
           + "delivered" + " Boolean DEFAULT false, "
           + "read" + " Boolean DEFAULT false, "
           + "hasobject" + " Boolean DEFAULT false, "
           ///object//
           + "object" + " text DEFAULT NA, "
           ///meta///
           + "deviceid" + " text DEFAULT NA, "
           + "modified_time" + " integer not null, "
           + "time" + " integer not null, "
           + "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS shared_index on messages(shared),"
           + "created_time" + " integer not null " + ")";


   public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGES);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        // db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS shared_index on messages(shared);");
      }
   }
```

Comment: @Rotwang, didn't think it that way. Please write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't**. Those are **separate** SQL commands - you simply **can't merge** them.

Mind that merging commands or queries by using `;` doesn't work in SQLite

Simply execute two consecutive `execSQL()` instructions and it'll be just fine.